# I need to create a Java date testing program

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I'm fairly new to Java and working on a program called GoodDate, where the program outputs YES or NO according to whether the argument is a valid date (using args in terminal). Since there are many possibilities, I've been briefed thanks to the wonderful internet that I should use a switch here, but I'm having trouble getting started. Any help for the n00b would be appreciated! I also already have a leap year program I could wrap into a class, here it is:

```
public class LeapYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        java.lang.String isLeapYear;

        isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0 ? "YES"
                : "NO");

        System.out.println(isLeapYear);
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing I guess you could clarify is what your actual problem is - do you have an exception, are you getting different numbers to what you expect, etc? You might also find it helpful to format that code so that instead of having a ternary statement all in one line, you use if statements to break out your logic so you can think it through a bit clearer?

Comment: Why not use a library with inbuilt functionality to validate date. Like `Joda Time`.

Comment: Because he's probably trying to solve the Java puzzles at Spotify, and you're not supposed to use external libraries ^^: http://www.spotify.com/us/jobs/tech/best-before/

Answer (score 0):

I'd make isLeapYear a `boolean` - true or false.  That's what that type is for.  Why would you make it a `String`?

I'd recommend moving that into a function on its own so you can reuse it:

```
public class DateUtils {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            // operate on arguments here.
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLeapYear(Date date) {
       return false;  // put your logic here.
    }
}
```

I don't see a single reference to a `java.util.Date` class.  You're doing yourself a disservice by not leveraging it.

The rest of your requirement is too vague to comment on.